# Is there a way to wrap pygame.midi.Input.read() in an asynchronous task without polling or an extra thread?

Tags: python, pygame, python-asyncio, midi

I have basically the following code and want to embed it in an `async` coroutine:

```
def read_midi():
    midi_in = pygame.midi.Input(0)
    while True:
        if midi_in.poll():
            midi_data = midi_in.read(1)[0][0]
            # do something with midi_data, e.g. putting it in a Queue..
```

From my understanding since `pygame` is not asynchronous I have two options here: put the whole function in an extra thread or turn it into an `async` coroutine like this:

```
async def read_midi():
    midi_in = pygame.midi.Input(1)
    while True:
        if not midi_in.poll():
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # very bad!
            continue
        midi_data = midi_in.read(1)[0][0]
        # do something with midi_data, e.g. putting it in a Queue..
```

So it looks like I have to either keep the busy loop and put it in a thread and waste lots of cpu time or put it into the (fake) coroutine above and introduce a tradeoff between time lags and wasting CPU time.

Am I wrong?

Is there a way to read MIDI without a busy loop?

Or even a way to `await` `midi.Input.read`?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the pygame library is not asynchronous, so you must either utilize a distinct thread or an asynchronous coroutine to process the MIDI input.

Using a distinct thread will permit the other parts of the program to carry on running concurrently to the MIDI input being read, but it will also necessitate more CPU resources.

Employing an async coroutine with the `asyncio.sleep(0.1)` call will result in a holdup in the MIDI input, although it will also reduce the CPU utilization. The trade-off here is between responsiveness and resource usage.

Using `asyncio.sleep(0.1)` will not be optimal as it will cause a considerable lag and it might not be wise to incorporate sleep in the while loop, as this will introduce a lot of holdup and won't be responsive.

Another possible choice is to utilize a library that furnishes an asynchronous interface for MIDI input, such as `rtmidi-python` or `mido`. These libraries may offer an approach to wait for MIDI input asynchronously without using a blocking call.

Comment: unfortunately both, `mido` and `rtmidi-python` cannot wait for input without blocking (without a timeout). `mido` itself is more like a wrapper for a number of backends (with `rtmidi` being one of them and it doesn't provide an asynchronous interface neither.